# How to automatically hide window form host contained control when scrolling goes up and down

Tags: .net, wpf

I am having pretty big problem with windows forms controls hosted in WPF. When, for example, user scrolls the window, the hosted control goes on top of the window, although it should be hidden.

I know this is known problem, and default behavior of hosted controls, but I think it can be solved if control's visibility is somehow binded with: whether other controls overlap it, or not. If other controls are overlapping, it should become Collapsed or Hidden, if not, it should be Visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just hide the part which was going to overflow on the window by using condition , 
that if scroll bar's vertical offset goes beyond a certain amount of value that just hide the part of control.